# Heroku fails at Start Script, but I have a standard start script in my package.json

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am working on a deploying a MERN stack application to Heroku. When run locally my project works perfectly but I face the following error when I try to run my application from Heroku.

> 2020-11-23T01:08:02.199575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 start script.

Here is the full logs from Heroku when I try to load the application

```
2020-11-23T01:08:02.199331+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-11-23T01:08:02.199575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mernshoppinglist@1.0.0 start script.
2020-11-23T01:08:02.199766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-23T01:08:02.875811+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-23T01:08:02.876018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-23T01:08:02.876125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T01_08_02_200Z-debug.log
2020-11-23T01:08:02.935584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-23T01:08:02.975882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-23T01:08:03.765808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=reke-mern-shopping-list.herokuapp.com request_id=0992d8aa-8716-407f-a59e-df58e9e39a54 fwd="208.102.105.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-23T01:08:04.134057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=reke-mern-shopping-list.herokuapp.com request_id=ba4d4159-75c3-458c-b3f1-cc1168ac4ca7 fwd="208.102.105.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

When I researched this error it was suggested that I add a start script to my package.json. However, I do have that in my package.json. I am curious if anyone would know the solution, OR, just as importantly, what steps I should take in trouble shooting this issue. Heroku deployment has been a real struggle for me. You can see the full file below

```
{
  "name": "mernshoppinglist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopping list with with the MERN stack and JWT",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "David REke",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "config": "^3.3.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.10"
  }
}
```

I am following along with a tutorial, and the best I can tell I have matched what the author has prescribed. I am not sure if it's needed, but below is also my server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const config = require('config')

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// DB Config
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

// connect to MongoDB

mongoose.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('mongoDB Connected...')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });

    

// use Route
app.use('/api/items', require('./routes/api/items'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'))

// added code from youtube comments
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

// Server static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))

    app.get('*', (req,res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    } )
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


 app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`))
```

Edit: I should add that I don't have a procfile, but my understanding is I do not need one because a start script in my package.json.

Edit 2: When I implemented chmsv's fix I recieved the following errors in my logs:

```
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235249+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235249+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235250+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235250+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235251+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235251+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235251+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2020-11-24T13:45:26.235252+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2020-11-24T13:45:26.307299+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-24T13:45:26.357136+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: When you open /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T01_08_02_200Z-debug.log, are there any more details?

Comment: if you do `start` as `concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"` should do it, since you are starting only your server now with `node server`, you need the client too

Comment: That edit2 is saying there is no file at "/app/server.js"  -- you need to find out where /app is being applied to the path since server.js is probably in your root directory. You could also just move server.js into a folder called "app" but it'll probably mess up all your other paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my issue came down to two different files and relative file paths where I did not have matching capitalizations. However, part of what caused issues for me was that I didn't know how to properly retrieve the correct logs. This youtube video was a huge help to me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U350rWtxGwg&t=1075s

Answer (score 1):

After the deployment, Heroku will run command "start": "node server.js" in your package.json. But anyway, Heroku demands the Procfile too.

1. Create Procfile and add `worker: node server.js`. If you use Github for deployment, don't forget to push change.
2. Open your app on dashboard.heroku.com. In Resources change Dyno type from web to worker.
3. Check Buildpacks (must be heroku/nodejs) in Settings.

Comment: I just implemented those changes and recieved a new set of errors I will put them in the OP.

Comment: @DavidReke Check once if the file path that heroku is taking is correct or not. 
Are you successfully able to build and run your application locally?
Did you do npm install before running? 
From first look, it shows that it cannot find node modules. Check if the node_modules folder has been created. Then restart the server.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I can run "npm run dev" and get the app to run locally. But When I run "heroku local" I get the same error of "cannot get /"

Answer (score 1):

All of these codes are completely correct. I was suffering from the same problem, and the problem was that I had selected add current ip address while creating the cluster.

So, in my case, changing the **network access** form anywhere in my MongoDB cluster, fixed the problem.

Also, don't forget to hit **restart all dynos**.